# Google Apps Script Query Formula

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the below code in an apps script linked to a spreadsheet.

```
function runQuery() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // Define your query configurations for each tab
  var queryConfigs = [
    { 
      sourceSheetName: "AllData", 
      targetSheetName: "All Pages", 
      targetCell: "A3", // Update the target cell as needed
      queryFormula: "SELECT A,B,C,D,E,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O" 
    },
    { 
      sourceSheetName: "AllData", 
      targetSheetName: "Low Linked Pages", 
      targetCell: "A3", // Update the target cell as needed
      queryFormula: "SELECT A,B,C,D,E,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O WHERE D < 35" 
    },
    { 
      sourceSheetName: "AllData", 
      targetSheetName: "High Single Anchor Pages", 
      targetCell: "A3", // Update the target cell as needed
      queryFormula: "SELECT A,B,C,D,E,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O WHERE H > 0.5" 
    },
    { 
      sourceSheetName: "AllData", 
      targetSheetName: "Unoptimized Pages", 
      targetCell: "A3", // Update the target cell as needed
      queryFormula: "SELECT A,B,C,D,E,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O WHERE J < 0.5" 
    },
    // Add more query configurations as needed
  ];

   for (var i = 0; i < queryConfigs.length; i++) {
    var config = queryConfigs[i];
    var targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(config.targetSheetName);
    
    if (targetSheet) {
      // Clear any existing data in the target sheet starting from the specified target cell
      var targetCell = targetSheet.getRange(config.targetCell);
      var numRows = targetSheet.getMaxRows() - targetCell.getRow() + 1;
      var numCols = targetSheet.getMaxColumns() - targetCell.getColumn() + 1;
      targetCell.offset(0, 0, numRows, numCols).clear();
      
      // Create a temporary sheet to store the query results
      var tempSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet('TempSheet');
      
      // Execute the query formula in the temporary sheet
      var queryFormula = '=QUERY(' + config.sourceSheetName + '!"A2:O","' + config.queryFormula + '")';
      tempSheet.getRange(1, 1).setFormula(queryFormula);
      
      // Get the values from the temporary sheet
      var data = tempSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      
      // Delete the temporary sheet
      spreadsheet.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
      
      // Write the data to the target sheet starting from the specified target cell
      targetCell.offset(0, 0, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    } else {
      Logger.log("Target sheet not found for configuration: " + JSON.stringify(config));
    }
  }
}
```

When I execute the code no errors show. However, on each target sheet I get "#ERROR!" as the output as opposed to the query output I want.

The "AllData" tab is properly populated with no blank or extra rows. I also double checked all the columns reflected in the code exist.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you didn't enclose the sheet name in single quotes, you need to change this line:

```js
var queryFormula = '=QUERY(' + config.sourceSheetName + '!"A2:O","' + config.queryFormula + '")';
```

To this:

```js
var queryFormula = '=QUERY(\'' + config.sourceSheetName + '\'!A2:O, "' + config.queryFormula + '")';
```

Google was throwing an error because it couldn't properly parse the query that your code was generating. In the future, an easier way to avoid mistakes like this is to use template literals:

```js
var queryFormula = `=QUERY('${config.sourceSheetName}'!A2:O, "${config.queryFormula}")`;
```

Comment: that worked! Appreciate the help